# How to log the activities only of a specific rule of Windows Firewall from PowerShell Or Other alternatives

Tags: windows, powershell, security, firewall, windows-firewall

I want to monitor network activities only of a specific rule in the Windows firewall.
Because the firewall makes huge logs of all the enabled rules which makes it hard to analyze traffic on 1 specific rule.

I also tried with command, but did not find any log option here:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "RuleXYZ*"
```

So is there any command to do that?

Other alternatives (non-PowerShell) are okay as long as they can log only a specific rule but not all the rules.

Comment: To clarify your question, are you only looking for answers that use PowerShell?

Comment: Try playing with this for a starting point perhaps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/network-security/windows-firewall/configure-the-windows-firewall-log it'd then just be a trivial matter of getting these from the Event Viewer security logs I would think to parse accordingly to get only the "allowed" events you need to log.

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate Yes other alternatives is okay as long as it can log only specific rule but not all the rules. Thanks

Comment: That sounds good, and you're welcome.  I hope one or more quality answers come your way, as I think you've asked a very good question.

Comment: Have you enable firewall logging?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Yes, But the firewall logs all the enabled rules which is hard to hard to analyze traffic.